# Overrunning Sentences within Emphasized Text When Using Microtype and Compiling with Lualatex

Tags: luatex, margins, hyphenation, microtype, emphasis

Consider the code which is to be compiled with `Lualatex`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[tracking=true]{microtype}
\begin{document}
\large
\emph{\lipsum[1]}
\end{document}
```

which produces the output

[image]

QUESTION: Does anyone know why some of the sentences are running past the margins when I use `Microtype`, and compile code containing emphasized text with `Lualatex`? How might I fix it?

Thank you.

Comment: you do get warned Package lipsum Warning: Unknown language 'latin'. Hyphenation patterns for
(lipsum)                'english' will be used instead.
(lipsum)                
(lipsum)                With LuaTeX, lipsum requires babel to get proper
(lipsum)                hyphenation (you can use \usepackage[base]{babel}).

Comment: and if you do what the warning says you get no overfull boxes

Comment: My crystal ball tells me you still have `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` and run LuaLaTeX.

Comment: Running your MWE, I get the same output as @DavidCarlisle, even without loading `babel`. Could you post the `log` file?

Comment: @Robert oops I'll change my answer, sorry I didn't actually look at the pdf the first time, I just silenced the warning and it looked fine.

Comment: @egreg No. Because of an earlier answer of yours, I try not to use it anymore compiling with `Lualatex`.

Comment: @mlchristians as Robert says I get the good output with lualatex on your example  (although using babel to get sensible hyphenation is good anyway) You might want to unaccept my answer so someone has a chance to debug the overfull boxes

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the problem is caused by an outdated TeX system, as was discovered in the comments to the OP's related question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/636496.

Answer (score 6):

If I run your example I get the output below, although it does get the warning

```
Package lipsum Warning: Unknown language 'latin'. Hyphenation patterns for
(lipsum)                'english' will be used instead.
(lipsum)                
(lipsum)                With LuaTeX, lipsum requires babel to get proper
(lipsum)                hyphenation (you can use \usepackage[base]{babel}).
```

If you add

```
\usepackage[base]{babel}
```

The warning goes, and in either case the output is

[image]

Bad linebreaking is to be expected if you try to hyphenate mock Latin with English hyphenation patterns.

Comment: But the `lipsum` in the MWE was merely to illustrate the actual problem I am incurring with paragraphs containing sentences in emphasized English.  I have used `microtype` for better output when compiling with `pdflatex`. Is it's use still advisable when using `lualatex`? Shall I modify the post to replace the Latin with an English paragraph? Many thanks.

Comment: @mlchristians microtype generally improves things but the reason your example produced very different output with luatex is the different hyphenation setup. there are minor differences in hyphenation between pdftex and  luatex even when using the same patterns but typically these don't show up in practice you usually get the same linebreaks if using thesame (or similar, as here) fonts.